# Login redirect url in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a website that have customer and merchant. Each of them have different login.
what i want is each user to login to his own view.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_customer=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_merchant=models.BooleanField(default=False)



class Customer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Merchant(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

views.py

```
#merchant view
def users_homepage(request):
    product = Product.objects.filter(merchant=request.user.merchant).order_by('date_added')
    itemsordered=OrderItem.objects.filter(merchant=request.user.merchant)
#customer view
def index(request):
    listing=Category.objects.all()
    product=Product.objects.all()[:8]
```

setings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/users'
```

please show me how i can do it.
thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to use `@login_required` decorator on the function base view and**

**if you are going to use class base view there is two way**

1. Through `LoginRequiredMixin` using inheritance
2. Through `@login_required` on the method or class level as well

Here give an example

- The first use function base view illustrating the login required

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_first_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome")

# if not define in settings.py 
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_second_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome")
```

> See this blog [decorator login required](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/07/working-with-django-view-decorators.html)

- The second use class base view with `LoginRequiredMixin`

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

 class ProfileCBV(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/cbs/login' # if not define in settings.py
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("Welcome")
```

- The third is login required in the class base view

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
 url(r'^profile/$', login_required(views.ProfileCBV.as_view()))

# if use in views.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators        import method_decorator

@method_decorator([login_required], name='dispatch')
class ProfileCBV(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("Welcome")
```

There is lots of views and mixin available like `UserPassTestMixin`, `PermissionRequiredMixin` etc
Here give a link [Views and mixin](https://ccbv.co.uk/)

let me know in a comment if you face any problem